# PNRP Speed - peer to peer

Tags: wcf, pnrp

Just curious to know what your experiences with PNRP are? I have been using WCF to code up a peer to peer application using WCF.

I support 2 different setups, one using PNRP (i.e. no server) and another setup using a central server.

The central server approach is really fast over a LAN, peers can connect in around 0.5 - 2 seconds max. With PNRP though it sometimes takes up to a minute for peers to connect.

Is this normal? Is something wrong with my setup?

Ages ago I disabled teredo, and that caused PNRP to run very fast. But at the end of the day we will probably need to keep teredo in the mix to help with our application running over a WAN.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have used WCF's Peer Channels in an application requiring a Transient Elected Server State. This only needs to work on the LinkLocal cloud, the peers will all be on the same subnet. It does seem to take an inordinate amount of time to register with a cloud, and I am not sure how to confirm if a particular peer is currently registered in a particular cloud (using the abstraction of Peer Channels), but otherwise I like the convenience of it.